# How do you limit a type to all primitive values and only some function signatures?

Tags: typescript, types, interface

I want to construct a type that allows the values of a "class" to be of any primitive type (or any type at all for that matter), however if its a function, then it needs to be of a certain signature, arbitrary function signatures shouldn't be allowed.

```
type A = ((e: Event) => void) | Exclude<any, (...args: any[]) => any>;
interface IFoo {
  [k: string]: A;
}

class Foo implements IFoo {
  public bar() {
    /*
     This function should be disallowed because its type is not (e: Event) => void)
    */
    return 'blue';
  }
}
```

I've tried the above; I would expect TS to throw an error when I'm defining `bar()` but it doesn't.

Is it possible to construct the type I'm after? If so, how? If not, why?

Comment: But a function of type `()=>string` *is* assignable to type `(e: Event) => void`.  See [this FAQ entry](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters) and [this FAQ entry](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-returning-non-void-assignable-to-function-returning-void).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd approach it.  First, for your `A` (which I'll call `AllowedProperties`):

```
type AllowedProperties =
  | ((e: Event) => void) // function that takes an event
  | { call?: never } // an object which is not a function
  | string
  | number
  | symbol
  | boolean
  | null
  | undefined;
```

That's a union of: primitives, the function type you want `(e: Event) => void`, and an object type *without a property named `call`*.  This last thing matches *most* object types, but *excludes* function types, since functions have a `call` method.  TypeScript doesn't have [negated types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4196), so `Exclude<any, Function>` doesn't do anything useful (it becomes `any`).

Then we have `Foo` implement `Record<keyof Foo, AllowedProperties>`, which will cause the compiler to check each property (and not require an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) in the class).

```
class Foo implements Record<keyof Foo, AllowedProperties> {
```

Let's look at how it works.  The following are all fine:

```
  str: string = "a";
  num: number = 1;
  boo: boolean = true;
  nul: null = null;
  und: undefined = undefined;
  obj: object = {};
  sym: symbol = Symbol("hmm");
```

And the method you want is also fine:

```
  methodTakingEvent(e: Event) {} // okay
```

A method taking a non-`Event` compatible parameter is an error, as desired:

```
  methodTakingString(x: string) {} // error!
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <-- Event is not assignable to string
```

A method requiring more than one parameter is also an error, as desired:

```
  methodTakingTooManyArguments(e: Event, x: string) {} // error!
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  //Type '(e: Event, x: string) => void' is not assignable to type '(e: Event) => void'.
```

---

Now for some possibly surprising things... A method taking a parameter of a type wider than `Event` is fine, since it will be happy with an `Event`:

```
  methodTakingUnknown(x: unknown) {} // okay
  // Event is assignable to unknown
```

A method of no arguments is also fine, because [functions with fewer parameters are assignable to functions that take more parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters).

```
  noArgMethod() {} // okay
```

Additionally a method returning something is fine, because [functions returning non-`void` types are assignable to functions returning `void`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-returning-non-void-assignable-to-function-returning-void).

```
  methodReturningSomething(e: Event) {
    return "okay";
  } // okay
```

Both of those last two put together means it's harder to outlaw your `bar()` method.  I'll get back to that in a bit.

Also, if you happen to want an object with a `call` property, it will also fail:

```
  pathologicalCase = { call: 12345 }; // error!
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  // Type '{ call: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ call?: undefined; }'.
```

That might not be an issue; if it is, you can probably find some other property of functions that you don't need to use (e.g., `bind` or `apply`).  Or maybe you don't need all three, so you change `{call?: never}` to `{call?: never} | {apply?: never} | {bind?: never}`.  The point is to make some type which allows most object types you care about but still excludes functions.  Without negated types, the closest you can get is to build up a list of acceptable non-functions instead of "negating" functions.

---

---

I'd be inclined to leave it there, but if you really need to prevent methods of no-arguments, then you could use a relatively complex [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) and [mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) type to express a generic constraint:

```
type AllowedProperties<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: infer A) => void
    ? 1 extends A["length"] ? (Event extends A[0] ? T[K] : never) : never
    : T[K] extends Function ? never : T[K]
};

class Foo implements AllowedProperties<Foo> {
```

By constraining `Foo` to implement `AllowedProperties<Foo>`, we can look at each property of `Foo` and make sure it matches what is spit out of `AllowedProperties<Foo>`.  Roughly, for each property, if it's a function then its parameter list must be of length exactly one, and `Event` must extend that only parameter... otherwise, the property is invalid. If the property is not a function, then it's valid.  Let's see it work:

```
  str: string = "a";
  num: number = 1;
  boo: boolean = true;
  nul: null = null;
  und: undefined = undefined;
  obj: object = {};
  sym: symbol = Symbol("hmm");

  methodTakingEvent(e: Event) {} // okay

  methodTakingString(x: string) {} // error!
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <-- '(x: string) => void' is not assignable to type 'never'

  methodTakingUnknown(x: unknown) {} // okay
  // Event is assignable to unknown

  noArgMethod() {} // error!
  //~~~~~~~~~
  // Type '() => void' is not assignable to type 'never'.

  methodReturningSomething(e: Event) {
    return "okay";
  } // still okay

  methodTakingTooManyArguments(e: Event, x: string) {} // error!
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  //Type '(e: Event, x: string) => void' is not assignable to type 'never'.

  pathologicalCase = { call: 12345 }; // okay
}
```

Now `noArgMethod()` is rejected (which would prohibit your `bar()`) and `pathologicalCase` is allowed (if it matters), as presumably desired.  The error messages on invalid function properties are a little weird (`is not assignable to type 'never'`) but maybe that's worth it to you.

---

So I guess it depends on whether you want to use the more simple code that plays nicely with the compiler but doesn't exclude no-arg methods, or the more complex code that fights against the compiler but behaves more closely to what you asked for.

Either way, hope this answer helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-YSDqd7ygEAgMeMdmIxBgUGkRlaaB1ZhSADp4LQwAZN3kOFBHsQDH1cgIBQeBmhgAD6DQRsDF2SgAEUAGIclINMQDYCA03MSxrGAKA0ygnUsIgRg2DTOA2HAWsonwydpxAUtMLnLCqlw-CdUcNNiFcTCwCuTCKKo4gaJXIg3T1C5iDMNhgGNFAPx3X0ZCzM0bTqIgMKkmSYUPUh4TqUN7SHY9T3PJBL2vW970fOxnzfD8vx-Wg-xMACgIoUDwMg6C0FghDkLsVD0Mw7DqhsfDNOk2S2jTUpgDTHQ9DQwtiwYnAuNoFicJqeLIpk40Et0JhRKQcSPUbNp9XGTcPFIddWm6M0oAtFSVHeANK2NfdjHDK5oxHAxkyG4ak3PdzkAAchasd2sDKt1H4LREqYCbCmKUpyhSmdkDnEhgKQKblLHBalqKiaXxKuA6zoB8giwABhbZkBFQJgiwWRMQAJgAZgAFgAVliFYB16qNzxG0aBqQcaDoCO73pKVEomBmJVtzDaCynVLGPLPaKFh17Qm7BYuVWWJzqEGJ8Cp-BQEgWAEGQe6P2wCA-SQIE8aoGgGGYdhOCif4oBufUtBFOoAG0AGlClse5HmhgBdWR9WlxWkDZ4TgCYYpxBffX0NaW9ZZMKIPhO7QivUpAQixDW-S1nWPgl6EcDaHVoXV23xDHe3HeKSgJYABi96G1aQcJIjYdRI6UNhrZV8PNeUJ3dlYnKbZKKOI7DqXFcpzUiE2SdngODBWZOYgA5575+b+XhhZeQE6nBObjShWF9MRboUR6M2MWxOo8QJcYiVsEk2DJBkqURmkMTpBkmUZbXWW5DkV9Jnk6j5AV0iFKFRXFSUBiGWUMXlU+lRVNUNRKsqG2NMdpuzbrBydO+d3rT1Wm9Ksu064MHNDIazYBGfqwg4wQyTKmDMB1-7gi6poS2eg0brXzHRbGs4KxkHxhNCIccJofzrOVZsPYlz-wXL2V+ukzK+1zBg7auNKFLhKmuDc25iF7iASDUBfVwbDTMjDKaFtlqoLzJtLGjDdo4MmvgqIFMazEMklFOSCkdRKUtC-Dm1s8q2GhLpLuwhgG6RMmeKGFkbx3gMA+J8r53yfm-GBZy-5ALAU8mgCCBgoIwTgkhFCaEMJZTCnhNMuiCpxUKklBhaUmKZVCrhUJtYVExWWkQ90D9KrVVqvVRqpxn5mlmgA1or9QbgKIJAqBlTYxjX2odTRBSkAdQQYAxayCVprXEZjeiONpG1LkWwBRwIrq6hunkYIj0TwH0JgjL6f1AZigHDQogVMqZAA)

Comment: This is a way better answer than I even dared hope for. Thank you!

Comment: Regarding the more complex type `AllowedProperties<T>` do you have a good resource where I can learn how to construct as complex types as that one?